# How to Prove that a 3-regular bridgeless graph has perfect matching?

Tags: graph-theory

Proove that a 3-regular bridgeless graph has perfect matching?

Answer (score 1):

This is Petersen's theorem. You can see the proof [here.](http://books.google.com/books?id=DfcQaZKUVLwC&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=three-regular%20bridgeless%20graph%20perfect%20matching&source=bl&ots=oUIqlnF8QE&sig=3KVYCjNa2LKT1G4aFGahszT5VoE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HSKvUonIDenjsASaoIGYCA&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=three-regular%20bridgeless%20graph%20perfect%20matching&f=false)

Comment: isn't there any alternative proof?